# How do I determine the path of an id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

The biggest problem I am having with learning jQuery is how I do get the path to a particular element, id, or class in my document? I have Firebug and the Firebug jQuery extensions installed, but I am not seeing a way to determine the full path. Any tips for a n00b?

Comment: IDs are unique...why would you need the full path?

Comment: I created [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206802/why-isnt-my-row-getting-added-to-my-table) to clarify where I was going with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible with an unique JQuery function... as I found [this](http://weber.lviv.ua/wordpress/2009/04/dom_path/).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set up a custom function to traverse the element's parents using the .parent() and .parents() functions. Here is some info:

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

and

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

You could run a simple script to check for existence and output that to an array or other type of variable.

Pseudo code:

```
function traverse_path(elementId) {
  if($('#' + elementId).parent()) {
    traverse_path($('#' + elementId).parent().attr('id'));
    return $('#' + elementId).parent().attr('id') + ' > ';
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you  have written valid HTML, all you need is the ID itself (the part in the id attribute of your element).  If your id is "myID1" the jQuery selector you need is `$("#myID1")` assuming you are using `$` for jQuery.

If you are talking about traversing the DOM tree to get elements without ID, look into the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), the function [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/), the [:parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) selector, the [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) function, and the [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function.  All these can help with DOM [traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're using Firebug, then you can simply look at this when inspecting any elements.

[image]

But that is usually used for other things, and using the whole thing is both inefficient and not recommended if used as a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to know the parents all the way up? Look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) and [this](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/).

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the path of your elemnt you wish to attach jquery too , you will find it as a breadcrumb in the firebug panel after inspecting it.