# Why isn't my row getting added to my table?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using [this article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) to create a way for users to enter in multiple rows on a single entry form. The difference of what the author is doing and what I am doing is that I am putting my fields into a table. The problem I have is that I am not getting new rows inserted into my table. My guess is that the script isn't finding `#editorRows` but since I am still only learning jQuery I am not 100% sure.

My HTML showing only relevant parts

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Request Details</legend>
    <table>
        <tbody id="editorRows">
            <tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Hours Requested</th><th>Request Type</th><th></th></tr>
            <tr class="editorRow">
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="deleteRow"><img src="../../images/site_icons/16/69.png" title="Delete" alt="Delete" border="0" /></a></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p><a href="/LeaveRequest/BlankRequestedDayRow" id="addItem">Add Day</a></p>
</fieldset>
```

My jQuery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#addItem").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
            });
            return false;
        });
        $("a.deleteRow").live("click", function() {
            $(this).parents("tr.editorRow:first").remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code in /LeaveRequest/BlankRequestedDayRow is being called, so my guess is that the code doesn't know where to put it. BlankRequestedDayRow adds:

```
            <tr class="editorRow">
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="deleteRow"><img src="../../images/site_icons/16/69.png" title="Delete" alt="Delete" border="0" /></a></td>
            </tr>
```

The full code of BlankRequestedDay as requested:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<EmployeePayroll.ViewModels.LeaveRequestRow>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EmployeePayroll.Helpers"%>

<tr class="editorRow">
    <% using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("requestedDays"))
       { %>
        <td><%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DaysRequested.RequestId) %><%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.DaysRequested.DateOfLeave.Date)%></td>
        <td><%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.DaysRequested.DateOfLeave.TimeOfDay)%></td>
        <td><%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DaysRequested.HoursRequested, new { size = 6 })%></td>
        <td><%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DaysRequested.RequestType, 
            new SelectList(Model.LeaveRequestType, "Value", "Text", Model.DaysRequested.RequestType), "(Select)")%></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="deleteRow"><img src="../../images/site_icons/16/69.png" title="Delete" alt="Delete" border="0" /></a></td>
    <% } %>
</tr>
```

Comment: whats the /LeaveRequest/BlankRequestedDayRow partial view's code look like?

Comment: Did you verify with FireBug that `/LeaveRequest/BlankRequestedDayRow` returns the proper HTML and that the `success` callback is invoked?

Comment: @curtisk I have added that as requested

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov How do I see the output and know that `success` is being invoked?

Comment: Oh... I think I know the problem. I found where in FireBug I can see the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if you're ajax call returns something ?

With firefox, you can use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/)'s console to inspect the call.

Answer (score 0):

mike, much as you have with the `$("a.deleteRow").live("click", function())`, you may have to do the same to the `$("#addItem").click(function() {})` portion as well, i.e.

```
 $("#addItem").live('click', function() {
```

might be worth gving that a try... tho' might not be so, as i haven't tested it but is certainly a possibility.

also, take a look at using:

```
$('#editorRows tr:last').after(html);
```

as an alternative. Plus, one last ditch, put an id on the table and try all of the above against the table, rather than the tbody.

**[edit]** - If you have no rows, there will be no `tbody` unless you have specified one yourself. the tbody only get's attached to the DOM automatically in the presence of existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was an error was being returned after calling my action in the controller. I was returning the wrong object type. After fixing that, it worked. Thanks all for getting me on track!